# PL/SQL to find Special Characters in multiple columns and tables

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, special-characters, regexp-like

I am trying to come up with a script that we can use to locate any special characters that may exist in a column of data except for period, dash or underscore, and using variables.

My Data - Employees table:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
 ID |   LASTFIRST | LAST_NAME | FIRST_NAME | MIDDLE_NAME
---------------------------------------------------------
 57 | Miller, Bob |    Miller |   &^$#*)er |      NULL
 58 |  Smith, Tom |     Smith |        Tom |         B
 59 |  Perry, Pat |     Perry |         P. |    Andrew
```

My Script:

```
VAR spchars VARCHAR  
spchars := '!#$%&()*+/:;<=>?@[\\\]^`{}|~'

select *
  from (select dcid, LastFirst, Last_Name, First_Name, middle_name,    
          CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(First_Name, '[ || spchars || ]*$' )
               THEN '0' ELSE '1' END AS FNSPC 
          from employees)
 where FNSPC = '0';
 /
```

And all rows are returned.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?  I want to only select Bob Miller's row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REGEXP, Schmegexp! ;-)

```
select * from employees
where translate (first_name, 'x!#$%&()*+/:;<=>?@[\]^`{}|~', 'x') != first_name;
```

That translates all the special characters to nothing, i.e. removes them from the string - hence changing the string value.

The 'x' is just a trick because `translate` doesn't work as you'd like if the 3rd parameter is null.

Comment: Exactly what I'd do, too. Only you beat me to the answer! *{;-)